# how to interpret the windows registry 'ShellState' value

Tags: windows, data-structures, registry

In the windows registry, under the key [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Curre ntVersion\Explorer], there is a REG_BINARY variable called ShellState, 44 bytes in length.  It looks suspiciously like a set of bit flags, but maybe there's some kind of struct present, really no way to tell from looking at it.  Anyway, does anyone have the breakdown for this beast, especially for Win XP SP2 or SP3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SHGetSetSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762200%28VS.85%29.aspx)() and the SHELLSTATE struct IIRC